# removeChild not working in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, removechild

I'm trying to **remove all the link elements** with a rel tag of "stylesheet" using `node.removeChild` from a webpage but it will not work.
I know chrome extensions have some limitations for security reasons but I don't seem to find if this problem is caused by these limitations or not.

If I log `styles[i].parentElement` it gives me the body element so that's working correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**manifest.json:**

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Leho Styler",
"description": "This extension gives leho a whole new styling to better please the eye.",
"version": "0.1.0",
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": [
      "https://leho.howest.be/*",
      "https://leho.howest.be/*/*",
      "http://leho.howest.be/*",
      "http://leho.howest.be/*/*"
    ],
    "css": [
      "reset.css",
      "leho.css"
    ],
    "js": ["leho.js"]
  }
]
```

}

**leho.js** (content script)

```
var styles = document.getElementsByTagName('link');

function init() {
    for (var i = 0; i < styles.length; i++) {
        if (styles[i].rel == "stylesheet") {
            styles[i].parentElement.removeChild(styles[i]);
        }
    }
}

init();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, change the Query to `var styles = document.querySelectorAll ("link[rel='stylesheet']")` - this gets rid of the unnecessary if-block. Second, are you sure the DOM is loaded when init() is called? For this, instead of calling init directly, try adding this line: `document.addEventListener ("DOMContentLoaded", init);` - this calls init once the DOM is available. As far as I know, this can also be done inside the manifest file, though I do not know what the default is.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to use querySelectorAll as I didn't think of that. Also I've tried to execute init on DOMContentLoaded but that didn't solve the problem. What did solve it though is using "run_at": "document_end" in the manifest as you suggested existed. According to Google: _"In the case of "document_end", the files are injected immediately after the DOM is complete, but before subresources like images and frames have loaded."_ [Chrome Content Scripts Reference](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) Now everything works as intended. Thanks @NikxDa for the help!